# Replace featured image when shortcode is present

Tags: customization

For my portfolio page, I want for certain items to display a video instead of just a still image for it's featured image. I have using a plugin to play the video on hover called upon by a shortcode. This I insert on each post with the help of AFC.

The custom field is called video_link and below I have tried to replace the featured image with the video by calling it via AFC if it's filled, I cannot get this to work.

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $additional_classes ); ?>>
        <?php if( get_field( 'video_link' ) ) {
            get_field( 'video_link' );   
        } else {
            if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() {
                <?php get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'portfolio-thumb', 'width' => 600, 'height' => 400, 'before' => '<div class="post-thumb">', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
             }
        }
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wp' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Any idea what is wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Below is the website I'm trying to get this to work on:[nordenson.nu](http://nordenson.nu)

Comment: The plugin is Media Hovers Wordpress Plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to pass post ID parameter in the get_field() if you get data using loop.
so pass the in the get_field(). because currently it is trying to get data from current page field.

Try this if it works :

```
if( get_field( 'video_link', get_the_id() ) ) 
{
     get_field( 'video_link', get_the_id() ); 

} 
else 
{
    if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() 
    {
        get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'portfolio-thumb', 'width' => 600, 'height' => 400, 'before' => '<div class="post-thumb">', 'after' => '</div>' ) );
    }
}
```

So full loop content will be below:

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $additional_classes ); ?> >
        <?php if( get_field( 'video_link',get_the_ID() ) ) {
            get_field( 'video_link',get_the_ID() );   
        } else {
            if( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID())) {
                get_the_image( array( 'size' => 'portfolio-thumb', 'width' => 600, 'height' => 400, 'before' => '<div class="post-thumb">', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); 
             }
        }
        ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wp' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</li>
```

let me know if it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Chetan and thanks for the very quick reply! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve it. The if( get_field( 'video_link', get_the_id() ) )  gets caught inside the post_class. You can see it live with this error on the page right now. So now I get neither video nor images. Do you have any idea of what to change to get it out of there?

Comment: i have updated with full code. please try to implement in proper way. this should be works. let me no if it will works

Comment: Hi Chetan, Thank you once again! Your update got me a bit closer now however it seems to just directly call the thumbnail even if the 'video_link" field if filled.

Comment: I can see there is two errors in console. these error cause issue rendering video. try to solve these error then check this should works properly.

Comment: Chetan, I resolved these two issues that came of an earlier attempt at making this using another plugin. But still can't get AFC to render the information now.

Comment: okay. did you try to check this fields contain actual data or not ?  what kind of data you are storing in get_field( 'video_link', get_the_id() ); ? try to print that data using **print_r(get_field( 'video_link', get_the_id() ));** then see it contain any data or not.

Comment: Ah! That solved it. Since it was a shortcode it needs to be printed out! Thank you so much, Chetan! I have visited your country a few times and have always found Indians to be some of the most pleasant and helpful people in the world! And once again I have proof of that! Thank you for your time and knowledge!

Comment: I'm glad that your issue has been resolved. thanks for your complement. :-)